# Grey level co-occurrences matrix 14 feature implementation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, glcm

According to [this Haralicks research paper](http://dceanalysis.bigr.nl/Haralick73-Textural%20features%20for%20image%20classification.pdf), there are 14 textural features that can be extracted from a GLCM.

I searched for a equivalent implementation in Matlab but found only 4 of them being implemented. Does anyone know of a library that I could use in Matlab that has all 14 of them implemented. Or else if there isn't such a good library for Matlab is there a implementation for C/C++/Java/C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this [library](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22187-glcm-texture-features) from Avinash Uppuluri on the MATLAB Central File Exchange do what you need?

Comment: i ran the code pasted by a user called will on 22 jul 2011 having the function -> function [out] = cad_glcm_features(glcm). But how do i know weather the implementation is correct ?

Comment: Just like any other code you use, you either have to trust the author or you have to go through it and check it yourself - if you're not comfortable with that, then write it yourself. I haven't personally used the code in Avinash's submission to the File Exchange, so I can't say whether it's bug-free or not. But I usually find that things on the File Exchange are pretty likely to give the right answers, even if they're not coded to professional standards.

Comment: Does someone know of a C++/C/Java or C# implementation ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have the whole Haralicks implementation for JAVA

https://code.google.com/p/jfeaturelib/source/browse/src/de/lmu/dbs/jfeaturelib/features/Haralick.java?r=12f3307427400fc77434e39ffed43c2c62d4bb98